# Firebase operation appears to be clearing my EditText on it's own

Tags: android, firebase

I have an `OnEditorActionListener` applied to an `EditText`

```
serviceComment.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            commentRef.setValue(serviceComment.getText().toString());
        }

        return false;

    }
});
```

Shortly after the `setValue` is executed, the text within my `EditText` vanishes. Commenting out the `setValue` code or running any other code does not cause the text to disappear. I believe the problem lies within the firebase operation. Is this a bug? What is happening?

Comment: Is it not that once `i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` is true, the content of the editor clears itself by default?

Comment: It shouldn't clear by default. I can create a different button with an onclicklistener, and as soon as perform setValue with getText of serviceComment, the edittext is cleared, so the oneditoraction has nothing to do with it

Comment: In fact, whenever I use setValue to push the contents of an EditText to the database, it clears that EditText. Even if I try to store the contents of the EditText in a variable and try to push it to the database, it clears out my EditText.